# Cannot run program "AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.232.09-hotspot\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, spring, maven, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I'm using JHipster to generate app in Spring, when I build with maven it happen the problem about environment maven following as:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time:  12.076 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-20T14:40:39+07:00
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.9.RELEASE:run 
  (default-cli) on project app-1: Could not exec java: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.232.09-hotspot\jre\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\ESR\JHipster\app1"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I'm using jdk-8.0.232.09-hotspot

How to fix the problem

Comment: Try to get rid of the space in the path by either using progra~1 or putting the jdk into c:\dev\jdk8

Comment: Hi @Marged: I have try put the jdk into c:/dev/jdk8, but it same error

Comment: As per title, the jre is being used while jdk is expected. What command did you run?

Comment: Hi @pmverma: I used: 'mvnw' after generated source: 'yo jhipster'

Comment: If the error is the same you didn't change the path